# Is it possible to play Minecraft 0.30c multi-player using the Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-launcher

I've enabled alpha builds in the Minecraft launcher and have selected `0.30c` as my version. It has opened and just gone directly to a world.

My question is, how can I play multi-player on Minecraft `0.30c`? Are there command-line arguments I can use?

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

There is no online connection / multiplayer code in `Alpha 0.30c`.

Multiplayer features in Minecraft first appeared in `Alpha v1.0.17_02`.